# Jquery - how to access next element

Tags: jquery

I have a list of links.

```
<ul class="categories-list">
  <li><a class="active" href="hematologia">Hematologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="biochemia">Biochemia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="endokrynologia">Endokrynologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="badania-moczu">Badania moczu</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="diagnostyka-alergii">Diagnostyka alergii</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="cytologia">Cytologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="koagulologia">Koagulologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="serologiawirusologia">Serologia/wirusologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="mikrobiologia">Mikrobiologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="mikologia">Mikologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="pasozyty-krwi">Pasożyty krwi</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="autoimmunologia">Autoimmunologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="choroby-dziedziczne">Choroby dziedziczne</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="parazytologia">Parazytologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="histopatologia">Histopatologia</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="badanie-kalu">Badanie kału</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="autoszczepionki">Autoszczepionki</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="plyny-biologiczne">Płyny biologiczne</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="proteinogram">Proteinogram</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-ogolne">Profile ogólne</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-narzadowe">Profile narządowe</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-geriatryczne">Profile geriatryczne</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-pcr">Profile PCR</a></li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-podrozne">Profile podróżne</a></li>
</ul>
```

I have also two arrows:

1. left
2. right

When I click on link, I add class "active" to ul > li > a.

I want to use arrows to navigate between elements on the list.

```
jQuery('.arrows a').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var active_element = jQuery( "ul.categories-list li a.active" );
        alert(active_element)
    });
```

I need to find next or prev element on the list (depends on which arrow is clicked) and programatically click on it to change active element.

How to achieve this ?

Comment: `active_element.next()` and `active_element.prev()`. https://api.jquery.com/next/ and https://api.jquery.com/prev/ respectively

Comment: `$('a.active').removeClass('active').parent().next().find('a').addClass('active')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use this script:

```js
jQuery('.arrows a').click(function(e) {
  if (this.textContent.trim() === 'left') {
    if($('ul.categories-list a.active').parent().index() === 0){ return false; }
    $('ul.categories-list a.active').removeClass('active').parent()
      .prev('li').find('a').addClass('active');
  } else {
    if ($('ul.categories-list a.active').closest('li').index() === $('ul.categories-list li').length - 1) { return false; }
    $('ul.categories-list a.active').removeClass('active').parent()
      .next('li').find('a').addClass('active');
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  border: black 1px solid;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class='arrows'>
  <li><a href='#'>left</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>right</a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ul class="categories-list">
  <li><a class="active" href="hematologia">Hematologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="biochemia">Biochemia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="endokrynologia">Endokrynologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="badania-moczu">Badania moczu</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="diagnostyka-alergii">Diagnostyka alergii</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="cytologia">Cytologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="koagulologia">Koagulologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="serologiawirusologia">Serologia/wirusologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="mikrobiologia">Mikrobiologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="mikologia">Mikologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="pasozyty-krwi">Pasożyty krwi</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="autoimmunologia">Autoimmunologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="choroby-dziedziczne">Choroby dziedziczne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="parazytologia">Parazytologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="histopatologia">Histopatologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="badanie-kalu">Badanie kału</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="autoszczepionki">Autoszczepionki</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="plyny-biologiczne">Płyny biologiczne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="proteinogram">Proteinogram</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-ogolne">Profile ogólne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-narzadowe">Profile narządowe</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-geriatryczne">Profile geriatryczne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-pcr">Profile PCR</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-podrozne">Profile podróżne</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is working, except when you go beyond the first or last element, so you need to treat these elements seperately, either blocking any further steps or looping them, like so:

```js
jQuery('.arrows a').click(function(e) {
  var active = $('ul.categories-list a.active');
  var activeIndex = active.parent().index();
  if (this.textContent.trim() === 'left') {
    if(activeIndex > 0) {
      active.removeClass('active').parent()
        .prev('li').find('a').addClass('active');
    } else {
      active.removeClass("active");
      $('.categories-list li:last-child a').addClass("active");
    }
  } else {
    if(activeIndex == $('ul.categories-list li').length-1) {
       active.removeClass("active");
       $('.categories-list li:first-child a').addClass("active");
    } else {
      active.removeClass('active').parent()
        .next('li').find('a').addClass('active');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  background: yellow;
  border: black 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ol class='arrows'>
  <li><a href='#'>left</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href='#'>right</a>
  </li>
</ol>
<ul class="categories-list">
  <li><a class="active" href="hematologia">Hematologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="biochemia">Biochemia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="endokrynologia">Endokrynologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="badania-moczu">Badania moczu</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="diagnostyka-alergii">Diagnostyka alergii</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="cytologia">Cytologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="koagulologia">Koagulologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="serologiawirusologia">Serologia/wirusologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="mikrobiologia">Mikrobiologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="mikologia">Mikologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="pasozyty-krwi">Pasożyty krwi</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="autoimmunologia">Autoimmunologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="choroby-dziedziczne">Choroby dziedziczne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="parazytologia">Parazytologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="histopatologia">Histopatologia</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="badanie-kalu">Badanie kału</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="autoszczepionki">Autoszczepionki</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="plyny-biologiczne">Płyny biologiczne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="proteinogram">Proteinogram</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-ogolne">Profile ogólne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-narzadowe">Profile narządowe</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-geriatryczne">Profile geriatryczne</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-pcr">Profile PCR</a>
  </li>
  <li><a class="" href="profile-podrozne">Profile podróżne</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```